# What is wrong in my sql WITH and SORT in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, column-alias

[image]

In the picture: I using pgadmin 4 and Postgres 9.4.

Comment: formatted text please, not pictures

Comment: use `order by lower(rq.status)` instead, or `order by 2`

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY

> ...can be the name or ordinal number of an output column (SELECT list
>   item), or it can be an arbitrary expression formed from input-column
>   values.

not an alias of list item, so use:

```
order by lower(rq.status)
```

or

```
order by 2
```